# how to convert ruby gem->ruby app->create web services out of different functionalities of that app

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fluentd

I am very new to Ruby so please excuse me if my question sounds silly...

I want to use a Ruby based logging framework called Fluentd-- it is available for installation as a Ruby Gem.

How do I convert this to regular Ruby app so that I can deploy it via a Cloud PaaS? Also, what is the easiest/quickest way to create web service end points for this app's functionality? Basically I want to consume this from a java app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these URLs:

click [1] http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

click [2] https://github.com/wallyqs/fluent-logger-rails

click [3] http://nubyonrails.com/articles/a-hodel-3000-compliant-logger-for-the-rest-of-us

You could use Ruby java bridge software or you could think of JRuby.JRuby is tightly integrated with Java to allow the embedding of the interpreter into any Java application with full two-way access between the Java and the Ruby code.

As far as cloud Paas is concerned check this out:http://www.engineyard.com/products/cloud